# How to host NextJS app with an Express server backend on same localhost port

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, next.js

I am trying to host my NextJS app built with React on the same localhost port as my express api-server backend.

Inside my express server api setting I have set my api server to listen on:

```
http://localhost:3000/graphql
```

how can I set it up such that when I go to `localhost:3000` I can see the frontend as well.

Right now I am getting an error:

```
Cannot GET /
```

I know I cannot use `"proxy":"localhost:3000/graphql"` how can I do this using NextJS?

Comment: You'll either utilize the built in [Next API Routes](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/api-routes-graphql) or you'll have to create a [Custom Express Server](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/custom-server-express)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `rewrites` key in `next.config`:

```
module.exports = {
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' && {
        source: '/graphql',
        destination: 'localhost:3000/graphql',
      },
    ].filter(Boolean);
  },
}
```

Just start you Next.js on any other port and all request to `/graphql` will be redirected to `localhost:3000/graphql`